# Closedness of a set by using convergent nets

Tags: general-topology, nets

I am currently studying about nets, so it is all new to me. There is one thing that I could not find anywhere, so I try ask here. (If you know a reference, please let me know.)

Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $A\subseteq X$. Is it true that $A$ is closed if (and only if) for every net $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ in $A$ is convergent in $A$? This certainly does if we were working with sequences. I am mainly interested in the "if" part.

What I know is that

> Suppose $x\in X$. Then $x\in\overline{A}$ if and only if there is a net in $A$ that converges to $x$.

If $M$ is a collection of limit points of every net in $A$, then $M\subseteq \overline{A}$. How to see that $A$ is closed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quoted statement tells you that if $x$ is the limit of a net in $A$, then $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$. Thus, if every limit of a net in $A$ is a point of $A$, then $\operatorname{cl}A\subseteq A$, and hence $A=\operatorname{cl}A$, and $A$ is therefore closed.

Comment: "Thus, if every limit of a net in $A$ is a point of $A$, then $\operatorname{cl}A\subseteq A$..." Could you please elaborate your "then" part here?

Comment: @James2020: The quoted statement tells you that every point of $\operatorname{cl}A$ is a limit point of a net in $A$, so if every limit point of a net in $A$ is in $A$, then so is every point of $\operatorname{cl}A$.

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot that every limit are assumed to be in $A$. What about the converse direction? If $A$ is closed. I am unsure if it is allowed to assume that assume that $x\in A=\overline{A}$, when $x$ is already in $X$, so that we can use the quote I stated in the post, and use that "for all" implies "there exists" (quantifier stuff)

Comment: @James2020: If $A$ is closed, then $A=\operatorname{cl}A$, every point of $A$ is automatically in $\operatorname{cl}A$ and hence is the limit of a net in $A$. But in fact it’s always true every point of $A$ is the limit of a net in $A$, whether or not $A$ is closed: if $x\in A$, the constant sequence at $x$ is a net in $A$ converging to $x$.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, I still could not grasp. You have a net $(x_i)$ in $A$ which converges to $x\in X$, then $x\in \overline{A}$ by quote. If assumed that $x\in A$, wouldn't it mean that $A\subseteq \overline{A}$, because $x\in A$ implies $x\in \overline{A}$? (I know that $A\subseteq \overline{A}$ is always true, but I can't find out why it is $x\in \overline{A}$ implies $x\in A$, when $x\in A$ is assumed). Hope you understand what I mean

Comment: @James2020: You’re assuming that $A$ is closed, and you want to show that if $\nu$ is a convergent net in $A$, then $\lim\nu\in A$. Let $x=\lim\nu$. Then $\nu$ is a net in $A$ converging to $x$, so by your quoted statement $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$. But $A$ is closed, so $\operatorname{cl}A=A$, and therefore $x\in A$.

Comment: No, what I meant is the converse direction ...to show that $A$ as closed in conclusion. What confused me is $\overline{A}\subseteq A$. (If a net converges to $x\in A$, then $x\in \overline{A}$, wouldn't it simply mean $A\subseteq \overline{A}$?)

Comment: @James2020: No. Suppose that every limit of a convergent net in $A$ is in $A$. Let $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$. Then by your quoted statement $x$ is the limit of a net in $A$, so by hypothesis $x\in A$.  Thus, $\operatorname{cl}A\subseteq A$, and since of course $A\subseteq\operatorname{cl}A$, it follows that $A=\operatorname{cl}A$ and hence that $A$ is closed.

Comment: OK, one last question about the hypothesis: Does the statement hold for every convergent net in $A$, or is it enough with exatcly one convergent net in $A$?

Comment: @James2020: The hypothesis is that for **every** convergent net $\nu$ in $A$, $\lim\nu\in A$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in \overline A$ and consider the net $\{x_U\}_{U\in I}$ where  $x_U\in A\cap U,$ and $U$ is a neighborhood of $x,$, belonging to the directed set of neighborhoods of $x$ ordered by reverse inclusion. Then, $(x_U)\to x$ and so $x\in A$ by hypothesis, so $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

What is *not* true is that every net in $A$ converges, but that **if** some net from $A$ converges to some $x \in X$, we know that $x \in A$.

Put otherwise: a convergent net with terms in $A$ cannot have a limit outside of $A$. For nets, this is an iff: if $A$ is closed it holds (consider $X\setminus A$ which is open etc.) and if it holds for all nets (which is hard to check, as there are many such nets with terms in $A$ ..) then $A$ must be closed.

For sequences we only have one direction ($A$ closed then no sequence from $A$ can converge to an $x$ outside of $A$) but not always the other way around. We do have this converse in metric spaces, and other first countable spaces, where sequences suffice to describe the topology.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your first paragraph correctly. You mean, the statement "If **every** net $(x_i)$ in $A$ is convergent in $A$, then $A$ is closed" is wrong, and there should be "If there **is** a  $(x_i)$ in $A$ is convergent in $A$, then $A$ is closed"?

Comment: @James2020 no I wrote it correctly: for every net in $A$: if the net converges in $X$ to $x$ then $ x\in A$. Or a convergent net from $A$ cannot have a limit outside $A$. So the statement is about nets which are already convergent.